# Find $E[XY|Y+Z=1 ]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let X, Y, and Z be three independent N(1,1) random variables. Find $E[XY|Y+Z=1]$.
I believe the formula for the answer would be Ex * Ey / area but am not sure if this is right and I don't know how to find Ex and Ey. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The $\sigma$-field generated by $Y+Z=1$ consists of either null sets or complements of null sets. Use the definition of conditional expectation to guess the answer.

Comment: I have not learned what a null set or complement is. Can you explain?

Comment: A null set is a set of measure zero. How do you define conditional expectation?

Comment: $E(XY|Y+Z)=E(X)E(Y|Y+Z)=1\cdot \frac {Y+Z}2$ where the first equality follows from independence and second from symmetry. Plug in $Y+Z=1$ to get your answer.

Comment: So 1 * (1)/2 = 1/2 is my answer? Could you clarify what you mean by saying the second follows from symmetry?

Comment: @A.S.: The $\sigma$-field generated by $Y+Z$ is different than that generated by the event $Y+Z=1$.

Comment: @copper The only reasonable way to interpret $E(Y|X=c)$ is $E(Y|X)(c)$ - especially when $P(X=c)=0$. @J: $E(Y|Y+Z)=E(Z|Y+Z)$ and $E(Y+Z|Y+Z)=Y+Z$.

Comment: @copper I define conditional expectation as the expectation E[XY] given Y+Z = 1. I don't quite understand what σ-fields are. What A.S said is not true??

Comment: @A.S.: You can define it as $E[XY | 1_C]$ where $C = \{ \omega | Y(\omega)+Z(\omega) = 1 \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat what does the formula you just stated mean?

Comment: @copper I see your point but that's the most boring definition possible ;).

Comment: @JonathanYoder: Can you be a little more explicit about how you define conditional expectation please?

Comment: From the law of the unconscious statistician - http://puu.sh/ljcg8/b79d97062b.png

Comment: How do you define $f_{XY | Y+Z=1}$? The event $Y+Z=1$ has probability zero.

Comment: f(xy,y+z)/f(y+z)

Comment: If that event has probability zero then it doesnt even make sense to solve for conditional expetation right?

Comment: There is a more general (but much more technical) definition that makes sense (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_.CF.83-algebra) and this was what I was thinking of when I made my first comment. In your case, I don't think it makes sense, since the chances of $Y+Z=1$ are zero.

Comment: Ah I see. I have not learned this content in my course. Do you think what A.S said is valid because it makes sense to me logically?

Comment: I don't know how to interpret what @A.S. wrote unless you use the more advanced definition (which I am not recommending at the moment), and if you use the more advanced definition, the answer to your question would by $E[X]E[Y] = 1$, since $E[XY]$ is a version of the conditional probability.

Comment: So, the short answer is that I think it is undefined in your case.

Comment: Conditioning on sets of measure zero is tricky as the result depends on the limiting procedure chosen. I chose the one natural procedure *for the way the problem was presented* - the one that can be intuitively understood. The other interpretation is of little use as it loses ALL features of the problem. But to quote Kolmogorov: "the concept of a conditional probability with regard to an isolated hypothesis whose probability equals 0 is inadmissible."

Comment: This is very strange because I don't think I am expected to use the more advanced method described in the link you sent me but I have copied the problem straight from my textbook. My professor said that the solution was something along the lines of "Ex * Ey / area" does that make sense?

Comment: @JonathanYoder: Are you sure that the problem is to compute $E[XY | Y+Z=1]$ and not something like $E[XY| Y+Z \le 1]$? The whole issue here revolves around the $Y+Z = 1$ bit. (And no, I do not think you are expected to use the advanced definition.)

Comment: http://puu.sh/ljewr/2588dd5d33.png - it is possible that the problem was worded erroneously. But I am in no position to say as I am very weak in this area of mathematics.

Comment: I actually do see what you mean with your previous comment.

Comment: @copper In elementary presentation, $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, so that $E(X|Y=c)=\int_R xf_{X|Y}(x|c)\,dx$ which leads to my interpretation of the problem. Jonathan, you can use this approach instead of mine - but they are equivalent.

Comment: @A.S.: That works nicely for suitable continuous densities. The distribution for $Y+Z=1$ doesn't fit this category. Furthermore, the density definitions agree with the Radon Nikodym style definition when the former is defined. Does A.S. mean almost surely?

Comment: Yes I have already stated that formula. This conversation has been funny because both of you are much more well versed in mathematics than me.

Comment: It is because @A.S. interprets the "$|Y+Z=1$" part differently than I do. An his interpretation doesn't make sense to me (because the conditional expectation, in the advanced definition, is not uniquely defined).

Comment: Out of curiosity if the problem had said E[XY|Y+Z]  and additionally
Y+Z=1 would it make more sense?

Comment: To deal with $E[XY|Y+Z]$ then you really need the advanced definition, otherwise I do not know how to interpret it.

Comment: Okay well I am just going to use the method A.S described and disregard the fact that Y+Z = 1 has probability of zero. Thanks for your help friends.

Comment: @copper I've never seen $E(X|Y=c)$ for continuous $Y$ interpreted as $E(X|I(Y=c))(1)$ - only in the way I mentioned above. And why would you interpret it in such a way? It kills ALL the information about the variables. The big part of motivation behind conditional expectation is so that we could condition on sets of measure zero in a non-trivial way. On top of it, to say that $E(X|X+Y=c)=E(X)$ regardless of $c$ goes against the intuitive notion that $E(X|X+Y=c)$ should be an increasing function of $c$.

Comment: @A.S.: I'm having difficult parsing your comment. My initial interpretation of the problem was with the more 'advanced' definition, in which case we have $E[XY| \sigma(1_{\{t| Y(t)+Z(t)=1\}})] = E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] = 1$ (with equality in a version sense). From a more elementary perspective, I have no idea how to interpret the expectation when conditioned on an event of probability zero.

Comment: @copper I use $X,Y$ different form the problem's statement (not necessarily independent except for in $E(X|X+Y=c)$ increasing in $c$ example). You interpret $E(X|Y=c)=E(X|\sigma(1_c(Y)))=E(X)$. I have never seen such an interpretation (in case of continuous $Y$) and it's a boring one - the answer is independent of $c$. The interpretation I have seen *everywhere* is $E(X|Y=c)=E(X|Y)(Y=c)$ in other words, $E(X|Y)$ evaluated for $Y=c$.

Comment: @copper For example for Brownian motion $E(W_2|W_1=c)=c\ne 0=E(W_2)$.

Comment: @copper Or even simpler: $E(Y|Y=c)=c\ne E(Y)$. Not having to use your interpretation was part of the motivation to define conditional expectation.

Comment: My focus here is on helping the OP (I was unsuccessful). For an event $A$, I interpret $E[X|A]$ as $E[X|\sigma(1_A)]$ which is neither novel nor peculiar. I do **not** interpret $E[X |Y=c]$ as $E[X]$ (the equality in my comment above comes from the fact the the event has measure 0). As to boring, I have no idea how to respond.

Comment: If $P[Y=c] = 0$ then you **do** have $E[Y|Y=c] = EY$. I'm not sure I am following your rather edgy tone here.

Comment: @copper What is the expected value of $Y$ given $Y=c$? Since $Y=c$ on $Y=c$, expected value of $Y$ given $Y=c$ is clearly $c$ and NOT $E(Y)$ - regardless of whether or not $P(Y=c)=0$. That's intuition and definitions should follow it. It would be oh-so inconvenient to have $E(Y|Y=c)=c$ in case $P(Y=c)>0$ and $E(Y)$ otherwise. Don't you want $E(Y|Y\in A)=\int_{y\in A}E(Y|Y=y)f_Y(y)$? It fails in your interpretation. To make it clear, if $P(A)=0$, it is not generally the case that $E(X|A)=E(X|A^c)$. No edginess implied.

Comment: @A.S.: Suppose $K=\{t | Y(t) = c \}$ has measure zero.  Then the $\sigma$ field generated by $1_K$ is ${\cal F} = \{\emptyset, K, K^c, \Omega\}$. Then for any $A \in {\cal F}$ we have $\int_A X = \int_A EX$, and it is clearly ${\cal F}$ measurable, hence $EX$ is a version of $E[X| \sigma(1_K)]$. This is the standard conditional expectation definition, for example, Durrett's "Probability: Theory & Examples", 4.1, p.190.

Comment: @A.S.: Perhaps this is the disconnect. I am defining $E[X|A]$ as the conditional expectation based on the $\sigma$-field generated by $1_A$, which is, of course, the same as the $\sigma$-field generated by $1_{A^c}$. If don't know how to interpret $E[X|A]$ otherwise if $PA = 0$.

Comment: There is some disconnect. Your can define $E(Y|Y=c)$ however you want for any $c\in C$ if $\mu(C)=0$ - it won't change in thing in the big picture. But you can't define $E(Y|Y=c)=E(Y)$ for ALL $c$ - that would be incorrect. The only correct way is to define $E(Y|Y=c)$ is as $c$ almost surely. Your definition doesn't apply for all $c$ when $P(A)=0$ as more subtelty is needed (you can use your definition for any particular $c$, but not for all $c$). Your definition won't allow decomposition on sets of measure zero - as I mentioned above. You need $E(X|Y=c)=E(X|Y)(c)$.

Comment: @A.S.: I am not **defining** $E[X|Y=c]$ as $EY$, I am finding a version of $E[X|Y=c]$ and it happens to be $EY$ when $P[Y=c]=0$. That is all I am saying and that is all I have said. If $Y$ takes the value $c$ with probability in $(0,1)$ then $E[Y|Y=c]$ is a function that takes possibly different values on $[Y=c]$ and $[Y\neq c]$ (the averages over those sets divided by the probability of those sets, respectively). Only if those averages match can you use $c$ as a version. So what you are saying is **not** true in general. This is standard conditional expectation.

Comment: @copper Restrict consideration to $P(Y=c)=0$ - otherwise our approaches agree. You use a certain limiting procedure to approximate a set of zero measure - but not the one that gives you a result that can be used in a more global fashion. We want $E(X|Y=c)=g(c)$ where the only reasonable choice is $g(Y)=E(X|Y)$ a.s. Any other choice of $g$ (such as $g=E(X)$ would be inappropriate. Does your definition satisfy $E(Y|Y\in A)=\int_{y\in A}E(Y|Y=y)\mu_Y(dy)$?

Comment: @A.S.: This is getting silly. I am not using any limiting procedure. I am just using the standard definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_.CF.83-algebra, see the Durrett reference above, see Doob's "Stochastic Processes", p.17, whatever. It is not **my** definition.

Comment: @copper You *interpret/define* $E(X|A)$ as $E(X|1_A)$ and then use standard definition of $E(X|1_A)$ (conditioning on *event* (here) vs conditioning on a *random variable* (in your links) - I've done the same mistake before and was corrected). But that's a *useless/boring* interpretation if $P(A)=0$ (as it doesn't satisfy decomposition property I mentioned). A *useful* interpretation if $A=\{Y=c\}$ is $E(X|A)=E(X|Y)(c)$ which satisfies decomposition property.

Comment: @A.S.: You can use whatever interpretation you want, but it is not standard and hence potentially misleading for the OP, regardless of the exciting utility provided by your interpretation.

Comment: @copper It's *the only* standard interpretation. As I mentioned, for Brownian motion $E(W_2|W_1=c)=c$. Will you say this is incorrect?

Comment: @A.S. Since  $E[X|Y]$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)$, there is some (version dependent) $\phi$ such that $E[X|Y] = \phi(Y)$. In this particular case we can define $E[X|Y=c] = \phi(c)$. With this definition (which obviously differs from my interpretation as $E[X| \sigma(1_{\{t | Y(t)=c \}} )]$) we get $\phi(t) ={1 \over 2} t$ in the example above and the answer you gave in your first comment is consistent with this.

Comment: @copper You equate a *number* $E(X|A)$ with a *random variable* $E(X|1_A)=E(X|\sigma(1_A))$. That's confusing two separate notions. In the least you need to equate it with $E(X|1_A)(1)$.

Comment: @A.S.: I know no other way of defining $E[X|A]$ for some general measurable set $A$.

Comment: @copper I understood that and that's why I've been trying to show you an alternative *useful* way which motivated development of conditional expectation. There is no way to define $E(X|A)$ *as a stand alone* if $P(A)=0$. You need pick some $Y$ s.t. $A=Y^{-1}(c)$ and define $E(X|A)=E(X|Y=c)=E(X|Y)(c)$. The answer will depend on choice of $Y$ and can be only understood as conditional expectation on sets of the form $Y^{-1}(c)$ - which partition $\Omega$ differently for different $Y$ even if they can agree on a particular $A$. It's a tricky...

Comment: ... Your choice of $Y=1_A$ and $c=1$ partitions $\Omega$ in a "boring" way and defines only $P(X|A)$ and $P(X|A^c)$ while the choice I presented partitions $\Omega$ in a richer way.

Comment: @copper Any *useful* definition of $E(X|Y=c)$ should at least yield a natural $E(Y|Y=c)=c$ for *all* $c$ s.t. $Y^{-1}(c)\ne \emptyset$. If, however, $Y^{-1}(c)=\emptyset$, only then it's wise to define $E(Y|Y=c)=E(Y)$ (i.e. $E(Y|\emptyset)=E(Y)$) which agrees with the consequences of your initial interpretation. However conditioning on an empty set is different from conditioning on a non-empty set of measure $0$ - the difference your interpretation doesn't pick up.

Comment: @copper You can make sense of $E(X|A)=E(X|1_A)$ (one-valued function=two-valued function) only if $E(X|A)=E(X|A^c)$ in which case of course both are equal to $E(X)$. If $P(A)=0$, there is an inherent asymmetry in conditioning on $A$ and on $A^c$ even though $\sigma(A)=\sigma(A^c)$. OTOH $E(X|A^c)=E(X)$, OTOH $E(X|A)$ depends on $A$ and further choices and can take any value in the convex hull of range of $X$.

Comment: @copper Lastly, while there are subtleties in conditioning on sets of measure zero, $E(X|A)=E(X|1_A)$ clearly doesn't agree with $E(X|A)=\frac {E(X;A)}{P(A)}$ in case $P(A)>0$ so it can't be right if $P(A)=0$ either.

Comment: @A.S.: I'm not sure what point you are trying to make. I still don't know how you define $E[X|A]$ for an arbitrary measurable $A$. You can make a reasonable case for defining $E[X|Y=c]$ since we can write $E[X|Y]$ as a function of $Y$. But in general, I don't know how to define $E[X|A]$ other than $E[X|1_A]$ which is (assuming $PA \in (0,1)$) $E[X|1_A] = {E[X \cdot 1_A] \over PA} 1_A + {E[X \cdot 1_{A^c}] \over PA^c} 1_{A^c}$.

Comment: @copper The point is that your definition is simply WRONG. If $P(A)>0$, we [*define*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) $E(X|1_A)=\frac {E(X;A)}{P(A)}$ - a NUMBER. Your definition defines $E(X|A)$ as (two-valued) a RANDOM VARIABLE. I also provided definition that covers the case $P(A)=0$ and agrees with the above definition in case if $P(A)>0$. You are confusing conditioning on an EVENT $A$ with conditioning on a RANDOM VARIABLE $1_A$ which are different, non-equatable concepts.

Comment: @copper Your definition yields $E(X|A)=E(X|A^c)$ for all $A$ - absurd. The definition I gave actually ties conditioning on the event with conditioning on a random variable (where to define the former you compute the latter at a certain value - to get a number, not a random variable).

Comment: @copper I made a typo in the two comments above. The correct version is "we define $E(X|A)=\frac {E(X;A)}{P(A)}$". $E(X|1_A)$ is defined as usual and you presented the correct form of it. To unite these two, note the $E(X|1_A)=E(X|A)1_A+E(X|A^c)1_{A^c}$.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this discussion, but I have a question... What would be the solution if the question statement was: "Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be three independent identically distributed random variables with the same mean $\mu$.
Find $\mathbb{E}\left[XY|Y+Z=1\right]$." where it does not specify the distribution, not even if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are discrete RVs? Should I assume that they are discrete? If yes, how do I proceed?